# Como adicionar uma chave específica num objeto dado em forma de array?

Tags: javascript

Estou começando em Javascript e tenho o seguinte problema:

Dado o array:

```
const game = [['John', 'rock'], ['Mayk', 'scissors']];
```

Eu preciso verificar quem é o vencedor (de um torneio de jokempô), ou seja, preciso comparar os elementos do array.

Para isso, pensei em transformar o array em objeto.

Então criei

```
const keys = [['name', 'play']];
```

E concatenei ambos os vetores da seguinte forma:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(keys, game);
```

Ai tentei transformar esse novo array para objeto assim:

```
function arrayToObject(array) {
    const keys = [['name', 'play']];
    let result = {};
    Array.prototype.push.apply(keys, array);
    for (const element of keys) { 
        result[element[0]] = element[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

E obviamente, imprimindo isto, deu

```
{ name: 'play', John: 'rock', Mayk : 'scissors' }
```

Preciso inverter as colunas com as linhas, colocar a chaves como "name" e "play".

Existe uma função para tal? Ou alguma outra sugestão mais simples?

Comment: Oi, Laura. Não entendi muito bem qual "estrutura" você quer criar. Poderia [edit] a sua pergunta para tentar detalhar um pouco melhor?

Comment: eu editei, mas não sei se ainda está claro. Basicamente eu queria colocar as chaves como "name" e "play", e não o primeiro elemento de cada vetor como chaves (como está imprimindo)

Comment: Tem que seguir esse caminho? Pergunto pois eu acho bem complicado para uma coisa tão simples que dá para resolver em duas linhas de código.

Comment: Qual deveria ser o resultado? Você só quer verificar quem ganhou? Se for isso, não precisa construir o objeto

Comment: Se for só para verificar quem ganhou: https://ideone.com/wDNVz4

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

Leia [Pedra, papel e tesoura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedra,_papel_e_tesoura) para regras.

Podemos criar um `rulesObject`:

```js
const rules = {
  "rock paper": "paper",
  "paper rock": "paper",
  "rock scissors": "rock",
  "scissors rock": "rock",
  "scissors paper": "scissors",
  "paper scissors": "scissors",
};
```

Podemos usá-lo para encontrar o vencedor:

```js
function findWinner(game) {
  const win = rules[game[0][1] + " " + game[1][1]];
  const winner = game.find((item) => item[1] === win);
  return winner;
}
```

Um exemplo:

```js
function findWinner(game) {
  const win = rules[game[0][1] + " " + game[1][1]];
  const winner = game.find((item) => item[1] === win);
  return winner;
}

const rules = {
  "rock paper": "paper",
  "paper rock": "paper",
  "rock scissors": "rock",
  "scissors rock": "rock",
  "scissors paper": "scissors",
  "paper scissors": "scissors",
};


let game = [
  ["Player1", "rock"],
  ["Player2", "paper"],
];
console.log(findWinner(game));

game = [
  ["John", "rock"],
  ["Mayk", "scissors"],
];
console.log(findWinner(game));

game = [
  ["John", "scissors"],
  ["Mayk", "paper"],
];
console.log(findWinner(game));

game = [
  ["John", "paper"],
  ["Mayk", "scissors"],
];
console.log(findWinner(game));
```

Answer (score -2):

Você tá colando a 1 entrada do array keys como a chave do objeto, e a 2 entrada como o valor, e você estava atribuindo element[0] como chave e element[1] como valor do teu objeto, então como você disse, obviamente deu o resultado ja citado:

Enfim eu consegui o resultado assim:

```
const game = [['John', 'rock'], ['Mayk', 'scissors']];

    function arrayToObject(array) {
        const result = {};
    
        for (const element of array) {
            const [name, play] = element;
            result[name] = { name, play };
        }
    
        return result;
    }
    
    const gameObj = arrayToObject(game);
    
    console.log(gameObj);
```

saída: